# Is Spain the only country that uses "vosotros" for "you all"?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, pronombres, españa, guinea-ecuatorial

Is Spain the only country that uses *vosotros* for *you all* (informal) instead of *ustedes*? (In the second-person perspective). Examples:

> Spain: *Vosotros sois inteligentes.*
>
> Other (?): *Ustedes sois inteligentes.*
>
> All: *Ustedes son inteligentes.*

Correct me if me (or my examples, most likely) are incorrect, but I want to know if what I learned is right :)

Comment: It is still used in Argentina as quotidian speech.

Comment: In Argentina: _Vos sos inteligente_.

Comment: @Rodrigo  *Vos* is singular, though, and thus equivalent to *tú/Vd.*.  *Vosotros* is plural.  (Theoretically: *vos sos argentino, y vos sos argentina.  Por eso, vosotros sois argentinos*, although there is no region I know of that activitely uses both *vos* and *vosotros*)

Comment: @Rodrigo, That's why I said "theoretically"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Vosotros* is used in the majority of Spain, Equitorial Guinea, and Western Sahara and for *ser* would take the conjugation you note.  The latter two have substantially smaller populations than Spain or any other Spanish-speaking country so they are often ignored in discussions on linguistic issues in Spanish (not to mention that in many if not most cases their Spanish-speakers are non-native).

In some parts of Andalucía, you will hear *ustedes* with a *vosotros* conjugation, but that is not considered part of Standard Spanish and is best to be avoided by people not from that region.

You can still hear *vosotros* used in parts of Latin America, but never as quotidian speech — it will always be in some sort of a heightened register (religious, poetic, ceremonial), and even then such uses of *vosotros* are rarer and rarer every day.

Comment: @Timtech In America we almost don't use _vosotros_, it has a more literary use. Although is very unusual to use it when you speak. But we understand it perfectly, is not a problem.

Comment: In América it's only in the Bible, or mimicking Spain accent, but it is not used but it is completly understandable.

Comment: @jaimecruztriana and even then, many Bible translations today use ustedes exclusively. Some dioceses even have permission to do most of the liturgy of the mass with ustedes now (I think the consecration is the only thing that must be vosotros)

Comment: Throughout Latin America, the majority of Bibles use the vosotros form for the 2nd person plural.  Almost everyone familiar with the Bible recognizes it, even if they don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

> Ustedes sois inteligentes.

This is simply wrong; it pairs third-person "Ustedes" with second-person "sois".

Comment: That example is for second-person, where "ustedes" is used in place of "vosotros", as it is in most parts of the world, except for Spain and a few other places.

Comment: @timtech Though Vds. is semantically 2nd person, grammatically it is 3rd.  98-99% of Spanish-spekers would hear "Vds. sois" as a subject/verb mismatch.  I don't like using the word "wrong" but it is definitely non-standard.

Comment: @guifa It's what I've been taught, sorry for the misconception.

Answer (score 0):

In Colombia we use *vosotros* but only when learning Spanish grammar in elementary, however we don't use it outside the notebook.