# Difference between Vosotros and ellos/ellas/Ustedes

Tags: formalidad, persona-gramatical

I am American learning Spanish on Duolingo.

Trying to understand the difference between vosotros (they all) and ellos/ellas/Ustedes (they all)

Is vosotros informal, whereas ellos/ellas/Ustedes is formal.

Comment: vosotros and ustedes mean *y'all*; ellos/ellas means *they*

Comment: Ellos(as) is the only 3rd person plural. As for 2nd pl., in practice, it depends on regional variations more than anything else. In Spain you say _vosotros cantáis_ while in Latin America you say _ustedes cantan_ (confusingly enough, _ustedes_ uses the same verb form as _ellos_.)

Comment: @walen - People who are already in the know can see that the answer can be found on the referenced page.  But for a confused beginner, I think we should go ahead and try to clear up their specific confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Meaning

**Vosotros** is the plural informal "you" in some countries.  In other countries, instead of *vosotros*, people say "ustedes."

But in all countries, the plural *formal* "you" is "ustedes."

You should pick the regional variant you want to concentrate on learning, and stick consistently with that; and make sure that your learning materials match up with your target variant.

### Conjugating verbs

How do you conjugate a verb with "ustedes"?  Exactly the same as for *ellos/ellas*.

That's why, when you read a conjugation table, you'll see *ustedes* listed in the same section of the table as *ellos/ellas*.  But the meaning is different, as explained above.

### Examples

#### Informal plural you

1. Countries that use *vosotros*:

> Pablo y Carmela, ¿vosotros **queréis** acompañarnos? | *Do you (plural, informal) want to come with us?*

2. Countries that don't use *vosotros*:

> Pablo y Carmela, ¿ustedes **quieren** acompañarnos? | *Do you (plural, informal) want to come with us?*

#### Formal plural you

All countries:

> Don Roberto, ¿usted y su esposa **quieren** acompañarnos? | *Do you (plural, formal) want to come with us?*

They

> Manuel y sus hermanos **quieren** acompañarnos. | *They want to come with us.*

---

Note.  If you want to communicate with people in or from Spain, learn *vosotros*.  Otherwise you can skip it.  For more details about *vosotros* regions, see [Is Spain the only country that uses "vosotros" for "you all"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/8576/9385).

Answer (score -1):

the confusion might arise from the fact that, meanwhile "usted/ustedes" is the formal pronunciation of the second person pronoun(**you**), is conjutated the same way as the third person(**he/she/they**) "el/ella,ellas/ellos".

so to begin i will explain how the second personal pronoun (**you**) works in Spanish

from the less formal to the most formal:

**Vos/Vosotros**

> this is the less formal use, you would use it in casual conversation , can be exchanged with you. additionally, this pronoun is only used by regions and has been totally removed from some countries: 
>   reference : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voseo#Geographical_distribution, countries that have discarded this pronoun will use "***Usted/Ustedes***" instead,
>   it has its own conjugations

***Tu*** (doesn't have a plural form)

> this is the most commonly accepted and used pronoun for the second person globally, it is also used for causal conversation but it adds a level of cordiality that you would use for people close to you, it has its own conjugation

***Usted/Ustedes***

> highest level of formality, you would use it with people you respect, regions where the "***vos***" has been discarded will use this to address strangers with respect, it doesn't have its own conjugation, it will use the same conjugation as the third person ***(he/she/they)*** - ***el/ella, ellos/ellas***

Comment: *vos* is informal and not substitutable for *usted* — countries that don't use *vos* will use *tú* for it.

Comment: Check the above answer: the level of informality where "vos" is used does not exist in the countries where "vos" has been discarded. 
Instead they will use "Usted" to address strangers.

Comment: *Everybody* uses *usted* to address strangers with the exception of maybe Spain and Cuba where you can find *tú* between people of a good +/- 15 years.  Any country that doesn't use *vos* (you) uses *tú* (you) instead, with *usted* (you) as the formal variant.  Only two-three countries use *vosotros* (y'all) —only Spain and Equatorial Guinea, plus Western Sahara, use it— with *ustedes* (y'all) as the formal variant.  In all other countries, the only word for *y'all* is *ustedes*.  I think you're confusing *vos* with *vosotros* (no one uses them both)